# ASP.NET Response Methods not Executed when they are encapsulated in ASP.NET AJAX Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have the following code

```
        // This calls a procedure that takes time 
        byte[] bytes = Export.export_products(this.LanguageID);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"WTC_Watches_"+DateTime.Now.Month+"_"+DateTime.Now.Year+".csv\"");
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
            stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.End();
```

This code executes on clicking of a button.

When i use the button in a ASP.NET UPDATE PANEL so that i can show the animation, The procedure executes but i dont get the dialog on clicking of it i can download the file that i generated.

I think the Response methods are not working if the page is not reloaded or postback since i am using ASP.NET Update Panel

Any help is appreciated.